# CSS marquee, how can I make the text move from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have made the marquee completely using `css`. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Vu/6/) of it. But I want the text to move from bottom to up. Currently  it is moving left to right. How can I make it move from bottom to up ?

*CSS*

```
/* define the animation */
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
} 

@-moz-keyframes marquee {
  0% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

/* define your limiting container */
.marquee {
  border: solid 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* this is the tray moving around your container */
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
  -webkit-animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
}
/* pause the animation on mouse over */
.marquee span:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<p class="marquee">
    <span>
        Hey! What's up? <br />
        Second Line <br />
        Third Line <br />
        Fourth Line <br />
        Fifth Line <br /    
    </span>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - are you trying to achieve something in particular or just trying to learn? You've asked three different questions about the same marquee now, making small modifications to it each time. Like I said - just curious :)

Answer (score 4):

Remove `padding-left: 100%;` and tweak the `transform` like

```
@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%); }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Vu/7/)

Explanation : `0, 0` means x and y axis respectively, so instead of using `(0,0)` to `(-100%,0)` which is nothing but you are moving the text on `x` axis, take the `-100%` to the `y` axis and get rid of `padding-left: 100%;` in `.marquee span`

---

As you commented that you wanted to show 1-2 lines on load and then start scrolling, so provide some `height` to the container element and use `padding-top` or you can use `margin-top` for your `span` element like

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Vu/11/)

Also, [@harry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035999/how-can-i-make-marquee-move-upwards/25036082#comment38938089_25036082) has suggested similar in his comment, [take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Vu/10/)

Comment: Actually, the starting point is off in this version (as it starts in the frame). It should start at 100%. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Vu/6/

Comment: @Damien I think thats logical, because he was moving on x axis, when he wants to move on y, the placement doesn't matter, still if you want to place the text to the right use http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Vu/9/

Comment: I don't mean the position of the text. I mean how it enters the frame. The original (horizontal) marquee has the moving content starting outside the frame.

Comment: Is it possible that only 2 lines are visible when the text is moving upwards ?

Comment: @saplingPro: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Vu/10/) or are you saying the height should be more but only two lines should be visible at any point of time?

Comment: @Damien Got what you were trying to say, updated, thanks

Comment: @Harry What property did you alter to resize the border ?

Comment: @saplingPro: How about marking this answer as accepted mate? You seem to be making use of this solution in your other thread.